# Finding throughput when Rx and Tx values are given

Tags: networking, throughput, dpdk

I have been trying to analyse throughput in the DPDK l2fwd application. I get the Rx and Tx values, from this how can I find the throughput?

Comment: Throughput is measured in frames per second or in bits per seconds. So along `Rx` and `Tx` values you also need time to find the throughput...

Comment: Okay! If i get the Rx and Tx values and I run a ping command to get the time. I can find the throughput as Throughput = Receive Window Size/ RTT. Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be default `l2fwd` statistics get updated every 10 seconds. So we need to get delta between current and previous `Rx` values and divide it by `10`, i.e.:

```
Avg_Throughput = (Rx_curr - Rx_prev)/10 (PPS)
```

We will get an average throughput in packets per second (PPS).

To get the throughput in bits per second, we also need a frame size times 8 bit:

```
Avg_Throughput = (Rx_curr - Rx_prev) * Frame_Sz * 8 / 10 (bit/s)
```

The result will be in bits per second.

Overall, the `l2fwd` is not designed to measure the throughput. It is easier to measure the throughput using packet generator, which usually just shows the value.

Comment: In packet generator, I do not see an option to find the throughput. There are options for Latency Jitters but not for throughput.

Comment: @Haritha you mean pktgen-DPDK? It shows `Pkts/s Rx/Tx` and `Mbits/s Rx/Tx`. Those are the throughput. [Here is an example.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/90e83dfe69a02ddc76c2dc674e35af656104c834/687474703a2f2f696d67322e70682e3132362e6e65742f5036436643692d6130363836484f62576c6333442d673d3d2f363633313730363538313935353639373839392e706e67)